# Buffer allocating with read (C)

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, allocation

I wonder if read function does allocate the Buffer size to the Buffer that passes to it or not?
I need to know that in order to see if I need to free the Buffer or not after I am done with it.

Here is the prototype of the function read :

```
ssize_t read(int fildes, void *buf, size_t nbytes);
```

Comment: No, it doesn't alloate anything. The caller is required to allocate the buffer.

Comment: How would you get the buffer that it allocates? It doesn't return a pointer.

Comment: The `buf` argument would have to be `void **buf` so that it could be used to update the caller's pointer.

Comment: Downvoted because this question demonstrates no research. All you have to do is read the man page.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah I didn't check it, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, read does not do any allocation.  It reads data into the buffer you provide as an argument, which must have been allocated by you prior to calling read.  You can use a buffer on the heap or stack, or a global buffer; its your choice.